# Drawing a Bitmap on a Canvas got scaled

Tags: android, canvas, view

I created a custom View, with two Bitmaps. When I use the Bitmap outside of my View, in an ImageView, the image is OK. I have to call `setDensity(240)` (hdpi device), but it's ok.
However, in the custom View, when I draw the same Bitmap on a canvas, in the `onDraw(Canvas)` overridden method, it's scaled again, the same way when I don't call `setDensity(240)`. 
Via debugging, I ensured that the density of the canvas and bitmap is 240, after the call.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {    
    _ingredient.setDensity(240);
    canvas.setDensity(240);
    canvas.drawBitmap(_ingredient, new Matrix(), new Paint());
    Matrix refMatrix = new Matrix();
    refMatrix.postTranslate(0, _ingredient.getHeight()-35);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAlpha(60);
}
```

The working ImageView, outside of my View.

```
Bitmap tertr = _cocktail.getCocktailBitmapImage();
tertr.setDensity(240);
ImageView in = new ImageView(this);
in.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
in.setImageBitmap(tertr);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.cocktail_date_image_layout);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relativeLayout.addView(in, params);
```

The first one is showing the image scaled up, just like the second one, without the setDensity call. The images were created at 72dpi. These images are given, I cannot change them. Am I missing one thing, or this is how Canvas works? The device used for testing is a DROID2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. The code snippet that caused the trouble was in the manifest file. 
We changed `<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>` to true. True is the default, but unfortunately I changed that while I was trying different approaches. With the new value, and the `setDensity()` methods, it's working.

Comment: Is this the answer? If so you can mark it as accepted, unless you think that @boulder's answer is more generally useful.

Comment: I did, but I had to wait 20 hours. :)

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap density isn't a screen density it will be drawn on but an "original" density of bitmap. This means in case bitmap and screen densities match, bitmap wouldn't be scaled. You should set bitmap density to 160 if you want image to be same size in dips as it is in pixels. Hope this will help.

Also I think you shouldn't modify canvas density.

Comment: Could you explain please, how the value of 160 came? As you can see in the code, I set the Bitmaps density to match the density of the screen.

Comment: 160dpi is a default Android density. If you set bitmap density to 160 and your screen density is 240, bitmap will be scaled up. If you set bitmap density to 240 it wouldn't be scaled on 240dpi devices but it would be downscaled on 160dpi devices.

Comment: Besides, where do you get bitmaps from? Are you getting it from resources or from some other source, network i.e.?

Comment: I use them as assets (asset folder). I still don't get, why my pictures are scaled, when I set their density to 240, and the density of the screen of the DROID2 is 240.

Comment: I think boulder is right, don't change the density of the canvas and/or the bitmap. Just use it...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option. If I don't change the density, the image will be scaled. The image can't be scaled, because it looks awful. I have to paint the image in it's original height and weight, which is only possible if the density is set. Also, we plan to release only on 240dpi devices. Any particular case where this might cause problem?

Comment: well if this image was designed for hdpi, then you should set it's density, right. btw why do you loading image from assets not resources?